# How can I connect to Netware, IPX and use BTRIEVE?

Tags: 12.10, networking, novell-netware

I have approximately 30 PCs connected in a network with Netware 6.5 and 5.1 servers using the IPX/SPX protcol. We still run this because the program runs with BTRIEVE (bd Netware and work only in IPX), we can't change the software installed, so we're starting to migrate to Ubuntu.

I can see the directory from the server Netware with NCPFS packet, and run the program, but in the moment to execute BREQUEST (utility of Btrieve) the DOSBOX tells me that SPX.COM is not loaded. So, what can I do?

PD: Just to be clear, we can't change the software in use now, because of valid unrelated reasons. I really need to connect Ubuntu to Novell and run the utility BREQUEST in a DOSbox for example.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: you can install DOS in virtual machine (VirtualBox for example) and run the exact environment as the old workstations. NCPFS is not enough to access btrieve - this is only for file access and I assume it access it through TCP/IP instead of IPX/SPX

Answer (score 1):

You can install NetWare, or whatever outdated OS is necessary for your IPX program in VirtualBox. Since VirtualBox runs anything that runs on an X86 chip, you can pretty much install an old workstation on it.